# Complex region plot

Tags: plotting, complex

How do I plot the following two sets in the complex plane:
$C=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|z^4\in[0,16]\}$
and the set of solutions of equation
$Re(\frac{2z+1}{z+1})>0$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should to submit bug reports to WTS: both `ComplexRegionPlot[
 Re[(2 z + 1)/(z + 1)] > 0, {z, -20 - 20*I, 20 + 20*I}]` and `ComplexContourPlot[
 Im[z^4] == 0 && Re[z^4] >= 0 && Re[z^4] <= 10, {z, -5 - 5*I, 
  5 + 5*I}, PlotPoints -> 50]` produce wrong results in 13.3.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: @user64494, there is no bug here and nothing to report. Either plot a smaller region, `ComplexRegionPlot[Re[(2 z + 1)/(z + 1)] > 0, {z, 2}]` or increase the number of points, `ComplexRegionPlot[Re[(2 z + 1)/(z + 1)] > 0, {z, 20}, PlotPoints -> 100]`. And your second example doesn't even make any sense (read the documentation on how to use [`ComplexContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexContourPlot.html)).

Comment: Could you convert to 2D for the first set?
`red = Reduce[0 <= z^4 <= 16, z, Complexes];`
`twoD = red /. {Re[z] -> x, Im[z] -> y};`
`reg = ImplicitRegion[twoD, {x, y}];`
`[RegionPlot[reg]]`

Comment: @Domen: My second example does make sense: $C=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|z^4\in[0,16]\}$ is a co-lmage of the segment. This is a one-dimensional set in the complex plane so `ComplexContourPlot` should to draw  it.

Comment: Domen: $C=[-2,2]\cup[-2i,2i]$

Comment: @user64494, as I've said: Read the documentation about the syntax for `ComplexContourPlot` and the examples therein. And please don't hurry and complain about non-existing bugs.

Comment: @Domen: You are right, `ComplexContourPlot[Im[z^4] == 0, {z,3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{z}, 0 <= Re[z^4] <= 16], 
 PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 4]` does the job.

Answer (score 3):

```
ComplexRegionPlot[Re[(2 z + 1)/(z + 1)] > 0 && Abs[z^4] < 16, {z, 3}]
```

[image]

Read @Domen's comment that there might be some problems if you use larger region of plot which should be compensated by larger number of plot points by setting, say, `PlotPoints -> 200`.

To depict the regions separately replace `&&` with `,` in the above code to get:

[image]

If the first set was not $|z^4|\in[0,16]$ but rather $z^4\in[0,16]$ then you can depict it as intersection of blue region with orange lines:

```
ComplexRegionPlot[0 <= Re[z^4] <= 16, {z, 3}, PlotPoints -> 200];
ContourPlot[{0, Im[z^4 /. z -> a + I b] == 0}, {a, -3, 3}, {b, -3, 3},
   PlotPoints -> 200];
Show[%%, %]
```

[image]

Yet another method which only depicts the actual intersection:

```
Reduce[0 <= Re[z^4] <= 16 && Im[z^4] == 0 /. z -> a + I b // 
   ComplexExpand, Reals];
Region[ImplicitRegion[%, {a, b}], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 3]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read "plot the following two sets in the complex plane" in the question? Pay your attention to "two sets".

Comment: Hope you understand that `Abs[z^4] < 16` is not $C=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|z^4\in[0,16]\}$. Don't hurry and  give wrong answers.

Answer (score 2):

- `0 <= z^4 <= 16` means that `Im[z^4] == 0` and `0 <= Re[z^4] <= 16`. Here we using `ContourPlot`+ `RegionFunction` to do this.

```
c = Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
  ContourPlot[Im[z^4] == 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[0 <= Re[z^4] <= 16]]]]
```

- The same as using  `ComplexContourPlot`+ `RegionFunction`

```
c=ComplexContourPlot[Im[z^4] == 0, {z, 10}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{z}, 0 <= Re[z^4] <= 16], 
 PlotPoints -> 60, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

[image]

- `ReginPlot` can also draw the region `Re[(2 z + 1)/(z + 1)] > 0`.

```
d = Block[{z = x + I*y}, 
  RegionPlot[
   Re[(2 z + 1)/(z + 1)] > 0 // Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 4]]
```

[image]

```
Show[c,d]
```

[image]